# Unable to login in custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-custom-user

I have custom user model that works goods for registration and creating superuser. But it fails to login. I have been trying to rectify the problem but couldn't find any potential errors...

Login Form is not logging in the user when I submit the form, it just says the user with that username already exists (it is kind of acting like signup page) How to resolve this issue or else i get a 'page not accessible contact owner of the site'

#models.py

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    organisation_name =  models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    contact_no = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta():
        unique_together = ['organisation_name','email']

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.organisation_name

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, organisation, email, password):
        if not organisation:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an organisation")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, organisation=organisation)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

#forms.py

```
class MyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = models.MyUser
        fields = ('username','email','password','organisation')

class MyUserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(label="password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=models.MyUser
        fields=("username","email","password","organisation")
```

#views.py

```
class indexPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/inner_index.html'

class Create_Organisation(CreateView):
    model = models.Organisation
    fields = ('__all__')
    template_name  = 'accounts/organisation_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:inner_index")

class Create_Accounts(CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = models.MyUser
    form_class = forms.MyUserForm
    template_name = 'accounts/create_account.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:inner_index")




class LoginPageView(View):
    template_name = 'accounts/login_account.html'
    form_class = forms.MyUserLoginForm

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        message = ''
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form, 'message': message})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                organisation = form.cleaned_data['organisation'],
            )
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/accounts/')
        message = 'Login failed!'
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form, 'message': message})
```

#urls.py

```
app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.indexPage.as_view(),name  = 'inner_index'),
    path('create_organisation/',views.Create_Organisation.as_view(),name='create_organisation'),
    path('create_account/',views.Create_Accounts.as_view(),name='create_account'),
    path('login_account/',views.LoginPageView.as_view(),name = 'login'),
    path('login_test/',views.Login_Test.as_view(),name='login_test'),
]
```

#login_account.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block body_block %}
<form method="POST">
  <h1>LOGIN</h1>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

#settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/login_account'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one major issue in your code. That is by using a generic `CreateView` to create your users it will not use your manager thus will not hash the password, so you need to override it:

views.py

```
class Create_Accounts(CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = models.MyUser
    form_class = forms.MyUserForm
    template_name = 'accounts/create_account.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:inner_index")

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.model.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect('accounts:login')
```

But, your main problem is because you are trying to validate a form with your login data, that is why you get `username already exists`. Because `ModelForm` will try to validate the `username` which is supposed to by `unique:

models.py (snippet)

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    ...
```

Also, `organisation` and `email` are not required for the default authentication `backend` (The form still usefull to easily render components tho):

views.py

```py
class LoginPageView(View):
    ...

    def get(self, request):
        ...

    def post(self, request):
        credentials = {
        'username': request.POST.get('username'),
        'password': request.POST.get('password')
        }
        user = authenticate(**credentials)

        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/accounts/')

        message = 'Login failed!'
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'message': message})
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I am able to login now. But there's one problem, a user is able to login even with wrong organisation and email (though they need the right username and password). I tried adding 'organisation' in the credentials in the **LoginPageView**, but still they are able login with wrong oganisation.


I can of course include just the username and password in login form (and it works fine) , but just want to know if i could use 'organisation' and 'email' in authentication

Comment: Of couse you can, for that you need to write an [`authentication backend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) that takes `organisation` and `email` into consideration. Because as I stated in my answer, the `default backend` only uses `username` and `password` as credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i've been trying to solve this problem for 3days and i finally did it guys the problem is in your forms.py which is:

```
class MyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta():
    model = models.MyUser
    fields = ('username','email','password','organisation')
```

in this form you use 'Class Meta' which is the one causing validation errors, you will notice that your python code will always stops at the `If form.is_valid():` because your form is not valid. The issue you're encountering is due to the CustomUser model's constraints, such as unique usernames or other field constraints, conflicting with the form's usage for authentication.
What i did was just a simple form which is:

```
class CustomUserAuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
   username = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

The reason I didn't use class Meta in this particular code snippet is that it's a simple Form and not a ModelForm. class Meta is typically used in ModelForm to specify metadata about the form's relation to a model, such as the model itself, fields to include/exclude, etc.If this form were related to a Django model and intended to serve as a ModelForm for that model, class Meta would be necessary to define things like model, fields, or other metadata related to the model-form association. But in the case of a standalone form not tied to a model, defining fields directly inside the class suffices.